# Convert list to list of lists

Tags: r, list

How can I convert the list of strings `a` to list of lists `b` as

```
a = list('A', 'B', 'C')
```

and the converted to

```
b = list(list('A'), list('B'), list('C'))
```

Comment: `lapply(a, list)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the function `list` to the list `a`:

```
lapply(a, list)
```

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "A"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "B"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "C"
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, using `purrr::map`:

```r
library(purrr)

a = list('A', 'B', 'C')
b = list(list('A'), list('B'), list('C'))

a %>% map( ~ list(.x)) %>% identical(b)

#> [1] TRUE

a %>% map( ~ list(.x))

#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "B"
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] "C"
```

---

Or simply:

```
map(a, list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option:

```
Map(list, a)
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "B"

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "C"
```

**Benchmark**

As suspected, `lapply` is the fastest.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, it seems `lapply` and `Map` have similar functionalities.

Comment: @ahbon Essentially, `Map` is a wrapper for `mapply`.  The main difference is the default for `SIMPLIFY`, which is `FALSE` for `Map` and `TRUE` for `mapply`. So, `mapply(list, a, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` would return the same.